# Firebase no responde la secuencia de un bucle FOR

Tags: javascript, html5, firebase

Estoy haciendo una consulta a mi base de datos de Firebase con un bucle for, pero este código de Firebase se ejecuta al terminar el for y no en el proceso de la secuencia y lo se porque lo pongo en la consola y lanza los datos leídos de Firebase al final y no entiendo porque y este es mi codigo:

```
var dias = 32
for (let index = 1; index < dias; index++) {
    var id = ('input'+index);
    var element = document.getElementById(id).checked;
    if (element == true) {
      var mes = document.getElementById('month').innerHTML;
      var año = document.getElementById('year').innerHTML;
      // concateno mi mes con un cero  y con el slice solo agarro los ultimos dos digitos
      var mescont = ('0'+mes).slice(-2);
      var fecha_completa = (index+'-'+mescont+'-'+año);
      console.log(fecha_completa);
      var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var database = firebase.database();
      console.log('Primer paso');
      database.ref('/fechas/' + userId.displayName+'/numero').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var username = snapshot.val();
        console.log(username['numero']);
      });
   }
```

y al final en mi consola me sale los valores de de 'fecha_completa' y 'primer paso' y al final los valores de username['numero']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no es un error realmente. Lo que está sucediendo aquí no es más que el asincronismo de JavaScript.
Lo que estás haciendo en las últimas 4 líneas de tu bucle for es un proceso que puede tardar tiempo, tiempo en establecer la conexión a la DB y encontar el dato que buscas. Javascript, para manejar mejor sus procesos, utiliza asincronismo. Lo que significa que ciertos procesos tardados delegaran el flujo de ejecución a la siguiente instrucción, mientras que el proceso tardado rsuelve. Cuando esté proceso tardado resuelve, pudieron haberse ejecutado más instrucciones debajo de esta. Cómo ejemplo claro está lo siguiente:

```
setTimeout( () => console.log("hola"), 3000)//tardará 3 segundos en ejecutarse.
console.log("mundo")//tardará menos de un segundo.
//Output: 
//mundo
//hola
```

En tu código estás manejando un proceso asíncrono al ejecutar está linea:

```
database.ref('/fechas/' + userId.displayName+'/numero').once('value').then(...
```

Es por esto que usas el método `then` al final, para manejar un proceso asíncrono.
El único inconveniente con `then` es que cedes el flujo de ejecución a un callback, mientras que las instrucciones debajo de el siguen ejecutándose, por lo que el bucle for continua y continua.

Para abordar el control del asincronismo, javascript implementa varias soluciones, entre ellas estan los callbacks, las promesas y recientemente añadieron las keywords async/await.

Mi propuesta de solución es que modifiques tu bucle con tal de que quede así:

```
async function tuFuncion(){ // para usar async/await debes encapsular el proceso en una función asíncrona.
let dias = 32;
for (let index = 1; index < dias; index++) {
      //Tu código...
      let snapshot = await database.ref('/fechas/' + userId.displayName+'/numero').once('value');
      let username = snapshot.val();
      console.log(username['numero']);
}
}
```

De esta forma, el código se detendrá hasta que se obtenga el "snapshot" (lo que necesitas de firebase).
Usando el ejemplo anterior, la implementación sería la siguiente:

```
async function decirHola() {
    await setTimeout( () => console.log("hola"), 3000)//tardará 3 segundos en ejecutarse.
    console.log("mundo")//tardará menos de un segundo, pero no será ejecutada hasta que termine la anterior.
}

decirHola();
//Output: 
//hola
//mundo
```

Cabe destacar que async/await, al ser una característica de javascript relativamente nueva, no es soportada por todos los navegadores. En el siguiente link [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=Async%20await) podrás ver qué navegadores si soportan está característica para estar seguro de que quieres usarla .

Comment: Gracias, en serio no sabia de async/await, mi antigua solucion era conectarme a la base de datos antes de ejecutar mi funcion, pero esta solucion es mas corta